# Get full "path" of SQL tables with R DBI package

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, r-dbi

I'm new to SQL so I don't know the correct wordings, sorry for that.

When I establish a connection with `dbConnect` of the **DBI** package, I can list all tables of the database:

```
> head(dbListTables(conn))
[1] "cdw_apps"                   "cdw_attachments"           
[3] "cdw_auditLogs"              "cdw_blueprints"            
[5] "cdw_businessObjects"        "cdw_businessObjectsActions"
```

However I can't access directly to these tables, they are nested (in some kind of "folders", I don't know the wording, again).

For example I have to do:

```
dbGetQuery(
  conn, 
  "select top 100 * from [vxda-prod-sqldw01].[vxrd_cdw].[cdw_apps]"
)
```

Is it possible to list the tables with their "path" (I mean `[vxda-prod-sqldw01].[vxrd_cdw].[cdw_apps]` and not only `cdw_apps`)?

Comment: What kind of database? Probably easiest to just show your `dbDriver` command.

Comment: In general tables are not stored in separate files.   The precise format for storage depends on the particular database (which the question did not state) but if we take SQLite as an example then a database is a single file that contains all its tables.

Comment: The "folders" you are talking about are called "schemas".

Comment: @jblood94 It's Microsoft SQL Server. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Many DBMSes support the `information_schema.tables` (and `...columns` for even more). Try `DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'cwd_apps'")`, it may give you what you need. On SQL Server, for instance, it includes the `table_catalog`, `table_schema`, and `table_name`, which are your `vxda-prod-sqldw01`, `vxrd_cdw`, and `cdw_apps` you are looking for.

Comment: (There are newer tables and accessors for table/column/object information, and some DBAs are not fond of `information_schema.*`, but it works well and is still maintained, afaik.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. `dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables")` gives the list with catalog, schema, table.

Comment: Are you saying that's what you need, or is there more to it?

Comment: Given your inexperience, you should avoid using 3-part names (i.e., <database>.<schema>.<table>) in your queries. Your connection should determine the current database to use for your objects. Why? Because if you reconfigure your code / application to use a different database, all those 3-part names embedded in your sql queries must be updated to reflect this change. We often do this when moving code between different environments like development, test, QA, production, etc.

Comment: @r2evans Yes. `dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables")` is what I need (but `dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'cwd_apps'")` returns a 0-row dataframe). You can write this as an answer if you want.

Comment: @r2evans it's `where TABLE_NAME`, in capital letters this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most databases support `information_schema.tables` (and `.columns`, `.routines`, and others I believe), and SQL Server is among them. While there are newer object-discovery tables/mechanisms specifically in T-SQL, these still work and are sufficient for this need.

For instance,

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables")
#   TABLE_CATALOG TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_NAME TABLE_TYPE
# 1     mycatalog          dbo     table1 BASE TABLE
# 2     mycatalog          dbo     table2 BASE TABLE
# 3     mycatalog          dbo   someview       VIEW
```

will return all tables (and views) visible.

Comment: Thanks. I just add that the column names are in capital letters (at least for me).

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Not sure why you needed to capitalize it in the *query* itself, it works the same for me regardless of case. In fact, `TABLE_NAME='cdw_apps'` and `table_name='cdw_apps'` and `table_name='CDW_APPS'` all work for me (and my table name), not sure why it's being more specific for you. (I'm not the DBA, perhaps I'm on a different compatibility-level that's changing some defaults.)